# Xamarin forms binding Label

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Basically I want to make functionality, when I input text to my Editor it will appear inserted data to my label. And if I will swipe page to another page, that data should be bind'ed to that label in previous page where I entered data.

So I have portable class. In that class I have method `public ContentPage CreatePage(MyObject thing)` here I define many Labels, boxes , buttons and etc. But I will indicate most important things: Here I am define my Label and Editor:

```
public partial class CoolPage: CarouselPage
    {
    public CoolPage()
        {
          foreach (MyObject p in things)
            {
                Children.Add(CreatePage(p));
            }
        }
    public ContentPage CreatePage(MyObject thing) {
        var emptyLabel = new Label
                    {
                        Text = "Text",
                        WidthRequest = 50,
                        HeightRequest = 50,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.White
                    };
                    ((StackLayout)page.Content).Children.Add(emptyLabel);

        var inputNumb = new Editor
                    {
                        Text=thing.Number,
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                        IsVisible = true,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.White
                    };
                    inputNumb.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Text");
                    inputNumb.BindingContext = thing.Number;
                    ((StackLayout)page.Content).Children.Add(inputNumb);
    }
}
```

I have tried to impelemnt such a event:

```
inputNumb.Completed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                inputNumb.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Text");
                inputNumb.BindingContext = thing.Number;
            };
```

but it is not working. And I think because it is on same method. Also I tried to do out of method scope, by implementing such a line on `CreatePage` method `inputCarNumb.Completed += InputCarNumb_Completed;` But then when you define your variable inputNumb it doesn't recognize and I don't know how to implement in other case. I know it is very simple, but I think I miss something by doing SetBinding / BindingContext .

Comment: Can you try `emptyLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding { Path = "inputNumb.Text", Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = this });`

Or create a property where on completed change property value and use property name in that place `inputNumb.Text`

Comment: @Vishnu ,thank you for comment. this approach : `emptyLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding { Path = "inputNumb.Text", Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = this });`  do not work. What kind of property to create? It will be setbinding property?

Comment: A property eg. `InputNumbText` in `CoolPage` with `get, set` and then bind that property in above `Path = InputNumbText` 


`OnCompleted` call set property value and call `OnPropertyChanged(InputNumbText)`

Comment: @Vishnu I tried, but it doesn't work. Maybe could you upload code to pastebin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem like this:

```
emptyLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Text");
emptyLabel.BindingContext = inputNumb;
```

Comment: @BinaryTale - Note that Xamarin team advises to set the binding context after the SetBinding statements for performance issues:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.BindingContext/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MyObject inherits from and implements INotifyPropertyChanged so that PropertyChanged fires whenever Number changes. I generally inherit from XLabs's ViewModel, and use their SetProperty method. Don't bother setting the binding in the event. But the 2nd parameter of SetBinding should be "Number" which is MyObject's property name. Also the BindingContext should = thing.